Close side panel when clicking one the map in Leaflet
I have an interactive map made with leaflet, on which I try to add a side panel to display the marker information.
When you click on a marker, the panel slides on the map from the left.
The opening and closing function works, but I guess it shouldn't.
For the moment, here is how I close the pannel.
   $('html').not(layer).click(function() {
      $('.sidebar').removeClass('slide')
    });

        layer.on('click', function() {
      $('#listings').html(html);
      event.stopPropagation();
      $('.sidebar').addClass('slide')
  });

I'm using event.stopPropagation(); without declaring the variable and it works. From the moment I declare it, like this : layer.on('click', function(event) {} it doesn't work anymore.
Does anyone have an explanation?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Centres de référence</title>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
      crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.5.3/leaflet.markercluster.js" integrity="sha512-OFs3W4DIZ5ZkrDhBFtsCP6JXtMEDGmhl0QPlmWYBJay40TT1n3gt2Xuw8Pf/iezgW9CdabjkNChRqozl/YADmg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
      crossorigin=""/>
    
    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
    <style>
      body{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin:0}
      .marker-cluster-small {
      background-color: #7A00E6;
      color:#ffffff;
      }
      .marker-cluster-small div {
      background-color: #7A00E6;
      color:#ffffff;
      }
      .marker-cluster-medium {
      background-color: #7A00E6;
      color:#ffffff;
      }
      .marker-cluster-medium div {
      background-color: #7A00E6;
      color:#ffffff;
      }
      .marker-cluster-large {
      background-color: #7A00E6;
      color:#ffffff;
      }
      .marker-cluster-large div {
      background-color: #7A00E6;
      color:#ffffff;
      }
      /* IE 6-8 fallback colors */
      .leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-small {
      background-color: #7A00E6;
      color:#ffffff;
      }
      .leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-small div {
      background-color: #7A00E6;
      color:#ffffff;
      }
      .leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-medium {
      background-color: #7A00E6;
      color:#ffffff;
      }
      .leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-medium div {
      background-color: #7A00E6;
      color:#ffffff;
      }
      .leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-large {
      background-color: #7A00E6;
      color:#ffffff;
      }
      .leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-large div {
      background-color: #7A00E6;
      color:#ffffff;
      }
      .marker-cluster {
      background-clip: padding-box;
      border-radius: 20px;
      }
      .marker-cluster div {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 15px;
      font: 12px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      line-height:2.3
      }
      .marker-cluster span {
      line-height: 30px;
      }
      .leaflet-cluster-anim .leaflet-marker-icon, .leaflet-cluster-anim .leaflet-marker-shadow {
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-in;
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-in;
      -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-in;
      transition: transform 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-in;
      }
      .leaflet-cluster-spider-leg {
      /* stroke-dashoffset (duration and function) should match with leaflet-marker-icon transform in order to track it exactly */
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease-out, -webkit-stroke-opacity 0.3s ease-in;
      -moz-transition: -moz-stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease-out, -moz-stroke-opacity 0.3s ease-in;
      -o-transition: -o-stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease-out, -o-stroke-opacity 0.3s ease-in;
      transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease-out, stroke-opacity 0.3s ease-in;
      }
      /* =======================================
      HEADER
      ======================================== */
      .map {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height:100vh;
      z-index:999
      }
      
    .sidebar{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-100%;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    -o-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    z-index:999
    }
    .sidebar.slide{
    left:0;

    }
      .filter-group{
      position:absolute;
      top:30px;
      right:0;
      z-index:999;
      background: white;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #7A00E6;
      border-radius: 4px;
      }
      .filter-group label{
      font-family:Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size:14px;
      color:#000
      }
      #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 600px;
      position: relative;
      }
      .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,.leaflet-popup-content
      {
      -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important ;
      -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
      border-radius: 0 !important;
      }
      .leaflet-popup-close-button {
      display: none; 
      }
      .leaflet-popup {left: -100px !important;border:2px solid #7A00E6}
      .leaflet-popup-tip-container {
      top: 10px !important;
      overflow: auto important!;
      }
      .leaflet-popup-tip {
      box-shadow: none !important;
      background-clip: none !important;
      }
      .leaflet-popup-content:before 
      {
      content: none !important;}
      .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper{font-size:1.5em !important;}
     .radio-wrapper .check2 {
        appearance: none;
        background-color: #dfe1e4;
        border-radius: 72px;
        border-style: none;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        height: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 30px;
      }
    
      .radio-wrapper .check2::before {
        bottom: -6px;
        content: "";
        left: -6px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -6px;
        top: -6px;
      }
    
      .radio-wrapper .check2,
      .radio-wrapper .check2::after {
        transition: all 100ms ease-out;
      }
    
      .radio-wrapper .check2::after {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        content: "";
        height: 14px;
        left: 3px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        width: 14px;
      }
    
      .radio-wrapper input[type=radio] {
        cursor: default;
      }
    
      .radio-wrapper .check2:hover {
        background-color: #c9cbcd;
        transition-duration: 0s;
      }
    
      .radio-wrapper .check2:checked {
        background-color: #6e79d6;
      }
    
      .radio-wrapper .check2:checked::after {
        background-color: #fff;
        left: 13px;
      }
    
      .radio-wrapper :focus:not(.focus-visible) {
        outline: 0;
      }
    
      .radio-wrapper .check2:checked:hover {
        background-color: #535db3;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="map">
    <div class="sidebar">
       
        <div id="listings" class="listings"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
      <nav class="filter-group relative">
        <div class="gaucher_filter_group">
        <div class="radio-wrapper">
            <input id="all" type="radio" class="check2" name="radiobtn"/>
            <label for="all">All</label>
          </div>
          
          <div class="radio-wrapper">
            <input id="region1" type="radio" class="check1 check2" name="radiobtn"/>
            <label for="region1">region 1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio-wrapper">
            <input id="region2" type="radio" class="check1 check2" name="radiobtn"/>
            <label for="region2">region 2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio-wrapper">
            <input id="region3" type="radio" class="check1 check2" name="radiobtn"/>
            <label for="region3">region 3</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio-wrapper">
            <input id="region4" type="radio" class="check1 check2" name="radiobtn"/>
            <label for="region4">region 4</label>
          </div>
        
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
   <script>
      var centres = [{
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
      {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                3.2803257,
                45.5400916
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Houses",
              "Name": "Sport Santé Plus",
              "Region": "region 1"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                3.2803257,
                45.5400916
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Houses",
              "Name": "Sport Santé Plus",
              "Region": "region 1"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                3.0943107,
                45.756723
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Houses",
              "Name": "Service Médecine du Sport-CHU Clermont-Ferrand",
              "Region": "region 1"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                3.1168203,
                45.7963865
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Houses",
              "Name": "ASM Sport Santé",
              "Region": "region 1"
            }
          },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                5.0096102,
                47.2922393
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Houses",
              "Name": "Maison sport santé de Chenôve",
              "Region": "region 2"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                5.7010333,
                46.837325
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Houses",
              "Name": "Maison sport santé Poligny",
              "Region": "region 2"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                5.5456829,
                46.674209
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Houses",
              "Name": "Maison Sport Santé EPGV 39",
              "Region": "region 2"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                4.8101816,
                46.7971138
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Houses",
              "Name": "Le CAP : Centre d'activités physiques adaptées et santé",
              "Region": "region 2"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                4.8609497,
                46.7818644
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Houses",
              "Name": "Maison Sport santé Le Grand Chalon",
              "Region": "region 2"
            }
          },
      {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                2.4914291,
                48.9133202
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Hotels",
              "Name": "Hôpital Jean-Verdier",
              "Region": "region 3"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                2.3376856,
                48.9121954
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Hotels",
              "Name": "BOUG'ERA 93",
              "Region": "region 3"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                2.5099226,
                48.8605785
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Hotels",
              "Name": "Maison Santé Sport Uni’Med",
              "Region": "region 3"
          }
          },
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                2.0022182,
                48.9819251
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Hotels",
              "Name": "Triel Sport Santé",
              "Region": "region 3"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                2.3613909,
                48.8375346
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Hotels",
              "Name": "InitiActiv Maison Sport Santé",
              "Region": "region 3"
          }
          },
       {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                -1.5039763,
                47.12207
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Houses",
              "Name": "Prophil Santé",
              "Region": "region 4"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                -1.6421183,
                47.0376511
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Houses",
              "Name": "Maison Sport Santé Saint Philbert de Grand Lieu",
              "Region": "region 4"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                -1.8816033,
                46.8441486
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Houses",
              "Name": "KINEO",
              "Region": "region 4"
            }
          },
      
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                -1.2892887,
                47.07819079999999
              ]
            },
            "properties": {
              "Category": "Houses",
              "Name": "MOUV SANTE",
              "Region": "region 4"
            }
          }
           ]
      }]
      
      var cartoDb = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
        attribution: '© <a href="https://protect-de.mimecast.com/s/OMi3ClRZ4EsX4ByLvt5ydCe?domain=openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors © <a href="https://protect-de.mimecast.com/s/06A9Cmq14NtW4mZvrI7kTg7?domain=carto.com/    attributions">CARTO</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd'     
      });
      
      var map = L.map('map').addLayer(cartoDb).setView([46.603354, 1.8883335], 6); 
      
      var clustersBounds;
      var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup({
        spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true,
        showCoverageOnHover: false,
        zoomToBoundsOnClick: true,
        iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
          var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
          var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();
          var stops = [];
          for (let i = 0, l = markers.length; i < l; i++) {
            var color = markers[i].defaultOptions.fillColor;     
            let startPercent = 100 * (i / l);
            let endPercent = 100 * (i + 1) / l;
            stops.push(color + ' ' + startPercent + '%');
            stops.push(color + ' ' + endPercent + '%');
          }
          if (window.document.documentMode) {
              var html = '<div class="markerCluster"><span>' + markers.length + '</span></div>';
            return L.divIcon({
              html: html,
              className: "marker-cluster"
            });
          } else{
            var html = '<div class="circleMarker" style="background: conic-gradient(' + stops.join(',') + '" >' + markers.length + '</div>';
            return L.divIcon({
              html: html,
              className: "marker-cluster",
              iconSize: L.point(40, 40)
            });     
          } 
        }
      });
      clusters.addTo(map);

      const regions = {
        region1: {color: '#2db034'},
        region2: {color: '#E87D1E'},
        region3: {color: '#E8001E'},
        region4: {color: '#2db034'},
      };

      

      function getLabel(id) {
        return $("#"+id).next("label").html();
      }
      
      const regionCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
      regionCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
        var regionName = getLabel(checkbox.id);
        if (regionName == 'All') {
          $('#all').on('click', function() {
            if (this.checked) {
              for (var regionId in regions) {
                clusters.addLayer(regions[regionId].layer);
              };
              map.fitBounds(clustersBounds, {
                padding: [50, 50]
              });
            }
          });
          }
        else {
          var layer = L.geoJson(centres, {
            filter: function (feature, layer) {
              return feature.properties.Region == regionName;
            },
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
              return L.circleMarker(latlng,  {
                "radius": 10,
                "fillColor": regions[checkbox.id].color,
                "color": "#ffffff",
                "weight": 1,
                "opacity": 1,
                "fillOpacity": 1
              });
            }
          });
          layer.addTo(clusters);
          regions[checkbox.id].layer = layer;

          $("#" + checkbox.id).click(function () {
            if (this.checked) {  
              clusters.clearLayers();        
              layer.addTo(clusters);
              map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds(), {
                padding: [50, 50]
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
      
      clustersBounds = clusters.getBounds();
      
      map.fitBounds(clustersBounds, {
        padding: [50, 50]
      });

      function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    var html = '';
    if(feature.properties.Category) {
       html +=  `<h4 style="margin:0">${feature.properties.Category }</h4>`
    }
    if(feature.properties.Region) {
       html +=  `<p style="margin:0">${feature.properties.Region }</p>`
    }
    if(feature.properties.Address) {
      html +=  `<p style="margin:0">${feature.properties.Address }</p>`
    }
    if(feature.properties.Phone) {
       html +=  `<p style="margin:0">${feature.properties.Phone }</p>`
      }
    if(feature.properties.Email) {
     html += `<p style="margin:0">${feature.properties.Email }</p>`
    }
    if(feature.properties.Website) {
       html += `<p style="margin:0">${feature.properties.Website }</p>`
    }
     $('html').not(layer).click(function() {
      $('.sidebar').removeClass('slide')
    });

        layer.on('click', function() {
      $('#listings').html(html);
      event.stopPropagation();
      $('.sidebar').addClass('slide')
  });

}
   </script>
  </body>
</html>




As per the [help/behavior], please do not include statements of appreciation within your posts.

event object you are referring to in layer.on('click', function() ... function is part of DOM Window interface. It's available as Window.event or solely event. It contains event which is currently being handled by the site's code, but is now obsolete and should net be used any more (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event).
If you declare event processing function with parameter layer.on('click', function(event) ..., this parameter is not original DOM event, but Leaflet event object (see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#event-objects).
For mouse event code should then look something like this:
layer.on('click', function(event) {
  $('#listings').html(html);
  event.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
  $('.sidebar').addClass('slide')
});


thank you very very much for these clear explanations, I wasn't aware of that.. I need to dive into this..
